# Roblox | How to make it so a MainModule script only runs of the owner of the group place or the owner of the place, owns a certain item?

Tags: roblox

How can I make it so a MainModule script only runs if the owner of the group place or the owner of the place, owns a certain item?

What would the line of code be?

Answer (score 0):

So long as the name of the module is "MainModule", it can be required (via AssetID) from any environment except on client.

## Code:

```lua
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local moduleToRequire = require(2368285483) -- set to your module's ID

function playerAdded(player)
    if game.CreatorType == Enum.CreatorType.User then
        if player == game.CreatorId then
            moduleToRequire() -- assuming your module returns a function; format to your module.
        end
    else -- has to be Enum.CreatorType.Group
        if player:IsInGroup(game.CreatorId) and player:GetRankInGroup(game.CreatorId) == 255 then
            moduleToRequire()
        end
    end
end

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(playerAdded)
```

When a ModuleScript is required, everything outside of what it returns is run once immediately prior to requiring it.

## References:

https://www.robloxdev.com/api-reference/function/Player/GetRankInGroup

https://www.robloxdev.com/api-reference/datatype/Enums

https://www.robloxdev.com/api-reference/function/Player/IsInGroup

https://www.robloxdev.com/api-reference/property/DataModel/CreatorId